# SwiperJS not working as expected. Same slides, one works and the other doesn't

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am having a bit of a problem using SwiperJS. I am creating a Weather App, and I display different pages, depending on how many location the user put. I used a Swiper to transition between these pages, and I have another Swiper to make another thing inside the page. I add these pages dynamically.

Strange things are happening, though. First, if I am on responsive mode, everything works just fine, but the transition between pages is lagging, a lot. But, when I change to desktop mode, it doesn't work. Even when I reload the page in desktop mode and when I change from responsive mode (working) to desktop mode.

This is not all. When I am in desktop mode, the first page switchs to the second just fine, but my second Swiper does not work. Strangely enough, it works on the second page, albeit in a unexpected and unwanted way. If I try to change to responsive mode, it does not work, and the transition between pages becomes lagged again.

Anyway, I think that it is related to the time I am initializing the swipers, but I have no idea what to do.

Here is the swiper code:

```
import Swiper from 'swiper/bundle';

function initSwipers() {
    console.log('hey');

    const swiperWeather24HoursContainer = new Swiper('.swiper-weather24hours', {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 5,
        pagination: {
            clickable: true,
        },
        touchMoveStopPropagation: true,
        observer: true,
        observeParents: true,
        breakpoints: {
            350: {
                slidesPerView: 4,
            },
            750: {
                slidesPerView: 6,
                spaceBetween: 5,
            },
            1000: {
                slidesPerView: 7,
                spaceBetween: 5,
            }
        }
    })
    
    const swiperPage = new Swiper('.swiper-page', {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        observer: true,
        observeParents: true,
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-page-pagination',
            clickable: true,
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
            prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
          },
    })
}

export {
    initSwipers,
}
```

And I am adding the swipers in these instances. First, I already have in my HTML the Swiper for the pages transition. So, when I create a page, I just add the 'swiper-slide' class and it is okay. This swiper works, the problem is the other one.

```
<div class="swiper swiper-page">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">

            <div class="add-new-weather-page swiper-slide">
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-page-pagination"></div>

        <!-- <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div> -->
    </div>
```

This swiper is for a container, where I have 24 items added dynamically and when I want to paginate through them. I create them this way. First, I create the container and after, I call a function to create the swipe-slides.

```
const divContainer = document.createElement('div');
    divContainer.classList.add('weather-24hours-container', 'swiper-weather24hours');

    const divWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    divWrapper.classList.add('swiper-wrapper', 'weather-cards-container');

    const forecastHourlyItems = getHourlyForecastItems(forecast);

    divWrapper.innerHTML += forecastHourlyItems;

    const divPagination = document.createElement('div');
    divPagination.classList.add('swiper-pagination');

    divWrapper.appendChild(divPagination);
    divContainer.appendChild(divWrapper);

    return divContainer;
```

Here is how I am creating the swiper-slides:

```
forecastHourly = forecastHourly.map((forecastHour) => {
        return `
        <div class="weather-card-hour swiper-slide">
            <p class="time">${forecastHour.time.split(' ')[1]}</p>
            <img class="img-weather" src="${forecastHour.condition.icon}">
            <p class="temperature">${forecastHour.temp_c}°C</p>
            <div class="chance-of-rain-hour-container">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-cloud-rain chance-of-rain-hour-icon"></i>
                <span class="chance-of-rain-hour">${forecastHour.chance_of_rain}%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        `
    }).join('');
```

And after all that, I initialize them AFTER they become visible. I even wrapped all my logic in a Promise to make sure the swipers were being initialized after the visibility. But it is not working, unfortunately. In responsive mode it does work, but when I go to desktop mode, it doesn't. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Start from basic simple "hello world" swiper (Work like it should or not?). Your Q is too long. Check if the DOM is ready when you load swiper (Also Check for console errors). Try to `update()` swiper (After the data loads). https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#method-swiper-update

Comment: Were you able to fix it ? I have the same issue, on the first slide some JS doesnt work, the second one is fine, the third is fine, the fourth doesnt work and it go on completely randomly... I have the same code on every slides.